# Как задать много знаков после запятой?

Tags: c#, double, типы

Как в double сделать 20 и более знаков после запятой? Или надо свой тип написать?

Comment: Совершенно непонятен вопрос: то ли вы хотите сделать, чтобы double всегда работал с точностью свыше 20 знаков (а это невозможно в принципе), то ли вывести число хотите с такой точностью (в таком случае знаки, начиная где-то с 15-го будут сомнительными для чисел, близких и больших 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) может вмещать в себя 15-16 знаков после запятой, поскольку он 64-битный. 

Если Вам необходимы более точные значения - воспользуйтесь типом [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). 
Он используется в каких-либо финансовых или научных вычислениях и имеет точность 28-29 знаков после запятой. 
Трудно представить реальную ситуацию, когда не будет хватать диапазона значений этого типа.

Ответ к комментарию:

Задачи не [этого](https://github.com/karan/Projects) проекта вы решаете?))

 Программно писать значения для 100+ знаков после запятой - это разве что действительно писать свой тип.

Я писал когда-то 100 знаков так:

```
private void RefreshPi()
    {
        decimal nextDigit1 = 0.8327950288419716939937510m; //26-50 digit after comma
        decimal nextDigit2 = 0.5820974944592307816406286m; //51-75 digit after comma
        decimal nextDigit3 = 0.2089986280348253421170679m; //76-100 digit after comma

        if (Pi.N_Digit <= 25)
        {
            Pi.DisplayPI = string.Format("{0:F" + Pi.N_Digit.ToString() + "}", PiModel.PI);
        }
        else if (Pi.N_Digit > 25 && Pi.N_Digit <= 50)
        {
            Pi.DisplayPI = PiModel.PI.ToString();
            Pi.DisplayPI += string.Format("{0:F" + (Pi.N_Digit - 25).ToString() + "}", nextDigit1).Substring(2);

        }
        else if (Pi.N_Digit > 50 && Pi.N_Digit <= 75)
        {
            Pi.DisplayPI = PiModel.PI.ToString();
            Pi.DisplayPI += nextDigit1.ToString().Substring(2);
            Pi.DisplayPI += string.Format("{0:F" + (Pi.N_Digit - 50).ToString() + "}", nextDigit2).Substring(2);
        }
        else
        {
            Pi.DisplayPI = PiModel.PI.ToString();
            Pi.DisplayPI += nextDigit1.ToString().Substring(2);
            Pi.DisplayPI += nextDigit2.ToString().Substring(2);
            Pi.DisplayPI += string.Format("{0:F" + (Pi.N_Digit - 75).ToString() + "}", nextDigit3).Substring(2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Например когда стоит задача вывести 100 знаков числа PI

Comment: @performance постарался ответить на ваш вопрос в ответе.

Comment: именно этот проект